# Translating virtual address to physical address in Windows kernel address space

Tags: windows, kernel, 64-bit, windbg, virtual-address-space

How does the translation from virtual to physical address work for kernel space virtual addresses (VA > `0xFFFF000000000000`) on Windows x64?

I know how it work for user space virtual addresses: the VA is made of multiple indexes in multiple tables, the first one (PML4) being located at the physical address stored in `CR3` register (and the process `DirectoryTableBase` aka "DirBase" in WinDbg). I guess this is similar for kernel space VA, but where is the PML4 table for them then?

My goal is to parse kernel crash dumps without relying on DbgEng/WinDbg API. I'm already able to tell where each memory page is located in the file, but most fields in the dump file are expressed in kernel space VA. The `DirectoryTableBase` field in that file header is related to the user space process which triggered the crash, so it does not help.

Comment: "Without DbgEng API" - why?

Comment: @ThomasWeller For performances, curiosity and portability. In particular, using SearchVirtual() is slower than searching in the dump file and translating file offsets to physical/virtual addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question: the PML4 table for each (user space) process does contain the mapping of kernel space VA. This is pretty counter-intuitive as it means the OS has to update the PML4 table of each process when it adds or removes high level VA ranges.

On a side note, if you intend to implement VA to PA translation on your own, take into account that the size of virtual pages on x64 can be 4 KB, 2 MB or 1 GB. I forgot about it, and that's why I was stuck and asked this question -_-